# Serial communication problem with Python/Arduino

Tags: python, pyside, pyserial, arduino-uno, qthread

`The functions that should communicate with Arduino aren't working. Serial connection opens, but the logic (turning diodes on/off does not work). I think that it has to do something with signals that I am doing wrong but I really don't know. I have 2 apps that should be controlling 2 RGB diodes on arduino, but it is not working. I had to try like this, because if I put more than 1 app that is using Serial port, I get the Code5 Access denied.

I tried this code:

class Worker(QThread):
signalData = Signal(str)
signalFinished = Signal()

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.ser = None

def run(self):
    self.ser = serial.Serial('COM1', 9600)
    while self.ser.is_open:
        try:
            text = self.ser.readline().decode().rstrip('\n')
            self.signalData.emit(text)
            self.control_led(text)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error during serial communication: {e}")
            break
    self.ser.close()
    self.signalFinished.emit()

def control_led(self, command):
    if command == 'turn_on':
        self.write_serial('1\n')
    elif command == 'turn_off':
        self.write_serial('0\n')
    elif command.startswith('analogWrite'):
        _, pin, intensity = command.split()
        self.write_serial(f'analogWrite {pin} {intensity}\n')
    elif command.startswith('k_turn_on'):
        self.write_serial('1\n')
    else:
        print("Unknown command")

def write_serial(self, command):
    command = command.encode()
    self.ser.write(command)

@Slot()
def writeData(self, command):
    self.control_led(command)
```

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
signalDataSend = Signal(str)

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    loader = QUiLoader()
    ui_file = QFile("automacija.ui")
    ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
    self.ui = loader.load(ui_file)
    ui_file.close()

    self.setCentralWidget(self.ui)

    self.temperature_humidity_tab = TemperatureHumidityTab()
    self.light_tab = LightControlTab()
    self.ac_tab = ACControlTab()

    index = self.ui.stackedWidget.indexOf(self.ui.page_3)
    index4 = self.ui.stackedWidget.indexOf(self.ui.page_5)
    index3 = self.ui.stackedWidget.indexOf(self.ui.page_4)

    page_3_contents = self.ui.stackedWidget.widget(index)
    page_4_contents = self.ui.stackedWidget.widget(index3)
    page_5_contents = self.ui.stackedWidget.widget(index4)

    for i in reversed(range(page_3_contents.layout().count())):
        page_3_contents.layout().itemAt(i).widget().setParent(None)

    for i in reversed(range(page_5_contents.layout().count())):
        page_5_contents.layout().itemAt(i).widget().setParent(None)

    for i in reversed(range(page_4_contents.layout().count())):
        page_4_contents.layout().itemAt(i).widget().setParent(None)

    page_3_contents.layout().addWidget(self.temperature_humidity_tab)
    page_5_contents.layout().addWidget(self.light_tab)
    page_4_contents.layout().addWidget(self.ac_tab)

    self.ui.btn_page_2.clicked.connect(self.stop_com)
    self.ui.btn_page_5.clicked.connect(self.start_com)

    self.ui.btn_page_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex((self.ui.stackedWidget.indexOf(self.ui.page_2))))
    self.ui.btn_page_3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex((self.ui.stackedWidget.indexOf(self.ui.page_3))))
    self.ui.btn_page_5.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex((self.ui.stackedWidget.indexOf(self.ui.page_5))))
    self.ui.btn_page_4.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex((self.ui.stackedWidget.indexOf(self.ui.page_4))))

    self.setWindowTitle("Automacija")
    self.setFixedSize(900, 500)

    self.th = None
    self.signalDataSend.connect(self.send)
    

@Slot()
def start_com(self):
    if self.th is None:
        self.th = Worker()
        self.th.signalData.connect(self.send)
        self.th.signalFinished.connect(self.th.deleteLater)
        self.th.start()

@Slot()
def stop_com(self):
    if self.th is not None:
        self.th.signalFinished.connect(self.th.quit)
        self.th.wait()
        self.th.deleteLater()
        self.th = None

@Slot(str)
def send(self, command):
    if self.light_tab.turn_on():
        command = "turn_on"
    elif self.light_tab.turn_off():
        command = "turn_off"
    if self.ac_tab.k_turn_on():
        command = "k_turn_on"

    if self.th is not None and command:
        self.th.writeData(command)

def open_close_menu(self):
  width = self.leftMenu.maximumWidth()
  fr = QFrame()
  if width == 200:
    self.leftMenu.setMaximumWidth(43)
  else:
     self.leftMenu.setMaximumWidth(200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   window = MainWindow()
   window.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec())`
```